# How to call release from COM server

Tags: windows, com

I am writing a Com server and I have wrote code that detect situation when COM client was closed unexpectedly, in this case I should close COM server inside COM server code.

How can I do this?

UPD: I have situations when COM server is hanged or more correctly I can't attach to COM server from COM client, but application that contains COM server is alive, so I think that COM server can detect that all old COM clients was disconnected/closed/crashed and application will restart because no new clients attached.

I have write the following code in COM client in separate thread

```
while(not we are closing)
{
   unknown->QueryInterface(IComServer, &server);

   if (server)
     return;
}
```

so the COM client can wait until server will really ready to work

UPD2: Just tested: after 12 minutes my COM server was closed

Comment: What do you think will be the benefits of doing that?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Obviously he doesn't want the COM server process hanging around for indefinite period of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

COM periodically pings clients to see if they are still alive and runs down interfaces from dead clients. So your server will find out eventually.

Comment: Never heard of this nor seen it myself.  I started an out-of-process server two hours ago and killed the client.  It is still running.  Love to see a reference for this, it doesn't google well.

Comment: The rundown should happen after either 6 or 12 minutes from client disconnect, fwiw.  And it does happen.  Did you put a breakpoint on the Release() method on your server object to confirm that it wasn't called?  There might be another reference keeping your server alive.

Comment: @Larry, I kept it simple by getting a single reference to the _Application interface of msword.  It ain't happening.

Comment: msword might have an extra reference from GUI, so it won't be auto-closed without user action. Plain COM servers receive `IUnknown::Release` calls when clients go dead.

Comment: No gui.  If this is real then surely it is documented somewhere?  Is this DCOM specific?

Comment: Created ATL EXE from template project, added coclass and DebugView'ed constructors/destructors. Instantiated COM from .JS `WScript.CreateObject` and put script into infinite loop. Terminated cscript.exe process - 6 minutes later received Release on my COM object and server closed itself.

Comment: Never see that ComServer rundown after 6 or 12 minutes, but I will check it

Comment: I don't think your QI call is reliable (Q update). COM might cache queried interface on the stub and never ask real server for it again. Additionally, a frozen server typically indicates a different problem (in server side code) and if your COM class is free threaded the QI call will just be satisfied on another thread leaving current freeze as it is. The relaible way is to call *real* method, e.g. IServer::Ping to make sure that the party on the other end is breathing well.

Comment: @Hans - This is discussed in `Essential COM`, specifically the section called `Lifecycle Management and Marshaling` beginning on page 236. It's also discussed in this KB article [How To Turn Off the COM Garbage Collection Mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171414).

Answer (score 3):

That's a vulnerability that exists whenever you have two or processes interop with each other.  One of them dies and the other one keeps running, unaware that there will never be another request again from the dead process.  In the case of an out-of-process COM server, nobody is going to call IUnknown::Release() to get the object destroyed.  COM does not otherwise have a built-in fix for that problem.  An in-process server doesn't have this problem, the crashed process takes the server out as well.  Which is a problem too, no nice cleanup, but easier to deal with.

Getting the server to recover from this is something you'll have to add yourself.  You could, say, have the client pass its process ID so that the server can obtain the process handle and detect when the client falls over with WaitForMultipleHandles().  Assuming they both live on the machine, that's certainly not a COM requirement and not something the server can find out.

Comment: I like your idea in such way - Com Client receive the Handle of Com Server, create thread with WaitForMultipleHandles and when Com Server fails it make null the pointer to the Server. So the client potentially will never call hanged server

Answer (score 0):

COM will release the server-side object in an out-proc server some time after the client dies but only if there's no call executing in that object. This is the key - COM can't possibly stop a call in progress. So the solution is to make methods short-running and guaranteed to finish in some short reasonable time like several seconds. This way once the client dies no new calls arrive from it and after some time the call in progress end naturally and then after a timeout COM releases the objects in the server and the server can stop naturally.